# Uncaught ReferenceError while creating Multistore

Tags: magento-1.9, error, multistore

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined at example.in/:69
Uncaught ReferenceError: Translate is not defined at example.in/:96 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at example.in/:120 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Varien is not defined at example.in/:244 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Varien is not defined at example.in/:367 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at example.in/:460
Uncaught ReferenceError: Catalog is not defined at example.in.in/:542 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at example.in/:628
```

How to resolve this issue. Please help.

Comment: you can provide screen shot or url i will check and tell.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because of multiple reasons

1) check whether `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` set as like

```
http://www.domainname.com/
```

2) check  URL are loaded from correct path ( example you are include JS and CSS from head.phtml, file path are correct in head.phtml or check corresponding layout file)

3) check in .htaccess and set RewriteBase correct setup like /Magento

Hope it will helpful for you.